# `\iffmode` fails for first token in matrix cells

Tags: math-mode, conditionals, matrices

`\iffmode` seems to fail for the first token in every matrix cell. Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
    \ifmmode A%
    \else B%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
    \foo\foo\foo\
    $
    \begin{matrix}
    \foo\foo\foo& x\foo\\
    \foo&x\\
    \end{matrix}
    $
\end{document}
```

What I expect it to output is this

[image: 1]

Yet, it outputs this

[image: 2]

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: This is known, use `\relax\ifmmode` instead.

Comment: Is this for academic interest or for a real use case? If the latter, please add the intended code. Anyway, the braces around A and B are wrong. Not in the sense they produce errors, but because conditional *don’t* take braced arguments.

Comment: @egreg, you're right, the braces in the MWE are useless (removed now). They were necessary in my original code, though. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks :)